# Ansible variables wildcard selection

Tags: ansible

The only way I've found to select variables by a wildcard is to loop all variables and test [match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings). For example

```yaml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ query('dict', hostvars[inventory_hostname]) }}"
      when: item.key is match("^.*_python_.*$")
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml | grep key:
    key: ansible_python_interpreter
    key: ansible_python_version
    key: ansible_selinux_python_present
```

- Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Neither *json_query([?key=='name'])*, nor *lookup('vars', 'name')* work with wildcards.

- Is there any other "wildcard-enabled" test, filter ...?

Note: regex_search is discussed in [What is the syntax within the regex_search() to match against a variable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/879313/ansible-syntax-for-regex-search-using-variable-to-match)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#select)/[reject](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject) with Jinja tests:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
  loop: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys() | select('match', '^.*_python_.*$') | list }}"
```

gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible_selinux_python_present) => {
    "msg": false
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible_python_version) => {
    "msg": "2.7.10"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Select is very efficient here.

Comment: Excellent! This will go in my snippet-library :-)  Oh, the amount of lists I will no longer need!

Answer (score 5):

Update for Ansible 2.8 and higher versions.

There is the lookup plugin *varnames* added in Ansible 2.8. to `"List of Python regex patterns to search for in variable names"`. See details

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup varnames
```

For example, to list the variables `.*_python_.*` the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', '^.*_python_.*$') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible_python_interpreter) => 
  msg: 'ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3'
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible_python_version) => 
  msg: 'ansible_python_version: 3.8.5'
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible_selinux_python_present) => 
  msg: 'ansible_selinux_python_present: True
```

Moreover, the lookup plugin *varnames* will find also variables not 'instantiated' yet and therefore not included in the *hostvars*.