# Java version compare not working in Ansible

Tags: java, ansible

My goal is to check if Java is properly installed and if the version is higher than 11.0.21. So I wrote the following code:

```
  - name: Fetch Java version
    shell: java -version 2>&1 | awk -F'"' 'NR==1{ print $2 }'
    register: java_version
  - name: Print it
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ java_version.stdout }}"
  - assert:
      that: 
        - "java_version.stdout | version_compare('11.0.21', '>=')"
```

Unfortunately it's not working properly:
[image]

Anyone an idea why?

I tried debugging it by printing the version number like mentioned in the code

Comment: `version_compare` is a Jinja test not a filter, you have to use it with an `is` not a pipe (`|`). See the examples in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/version_test.html#examples

Comment: Additionally, I'd recommend to use `changed_when: false` on a `shell` task so that in the play recap this task is not indicated as changed. Also, `awk` might not be available on every system, so it could be worth to parse the output using Ansible as well.

Comment: OP asked a clear question and showed an attempt at solving it, this should not be downvoted.

Comment: @julaine, actually this question is in addition to the syntax error a duplicate. See in example [How to compare version numbers of software using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75220137/6771046).

Comment: @julaine moreover this question shows code or output in a screen capture instead of in a code block which has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]

Comment: @julaine, sorry but, at least to me, « I blindly copied what ChatGPT proposed » [does not qualify to the level of research you are expect to provide on this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: I debugged it properly with error messages and in the end was able to find the answer myself. Same could happen if I read an old stackoverflow answer using the depricated function, so just throwing your anger at "ChatGPT bad" is not contributing at any level.

Comment: @julaine, thank you for your understanding. I also don't see why the downvotes are justified, except at using a screenshot.

Comment: @Zeitounator, thanks for the tip, will post the error as text in the future.

Comment: @faze you can edit the post to put in the text and remove the image

Comment: @julaine, doesn't matter anymore. The toxic moderators said it was unproduceable. This platform is such a joke

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to let Ansible fetch information about the installed package, and test your use case against that.

```yaml
- name: get all installed packages
  package_facts:
    manager: auto

- debug:
    msg: 'version is ok'
  when: item.version >= '5.3.0'
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['javapackages-filesystem'] }}"
```

Comment: javapackage-filesystem is not the same as the java version.

Comment: @Squashman, I interpret the answer to be meant as a recommendation of [using `package_facts` instead of `shell` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76313048/6771046), just showing it with a similar package (name).

Comment: @U880D in order to use package facts to get the version you would have to use some kind of wildcard matching because what if you didn't know if you had java-1.8.0-openjdk, java-11-openjdk or java-17-openjdk installed.

Comment: @Squashman, you mean like `"{{ (ansible_facts.packages).keys() | select('match', '^java.*$') | list }}"` and as in [Ansible variables wildcard selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54421688/6771046) ...

Comment: Perhaps you need to know which package holds the version you’re looking for?

Answer (score -3):

Compare version is depricated. Working code:

```
  - name: Fetch Java version
    shell: java -version 2>&1 | awk -F'"' 'NR==1{ print $2 }'
    register: java_version
  - name: Print Java version
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ java_version.stdout }}"
  - name: Check if java is properly installed and version is higher or equal than 11.0.21
    assert:
      that: 
        - "java_version.stdout is version('11.0.21', '>=')"
```

Chatgpt, perplexity are all trained with depricated code